# HIVE table from csv doesn't skip header

Tags: csv, hive

I try to create a table but it always keeps the header I already have as a table row

```
DROP TABLE if exists schema.datasets;
CREATE TABLE schema.datasets
( YM_x String, OPER_Y_x String)
COMMENT 'from csv file'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '073';
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "datasets.csv"
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE schema.datasets;
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

I found out it is necessary to use `tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")` but it gives an error
and seems to reside in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to bring the tblproperties while creating the table as below:

```
 DROP TABLE if exists schema.datasets;

 CREATE TABLE schema.datasets
 ( 
   YM_x String, 
   OPER_Y_x String
 ) COMMENT 'from csv file'
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '073'
   STORED AS TEXTFILE
   tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1"); 

   LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "datasets.csv" OVERWRITE INTO TABLE schema.datasets;
```